# Using a C++ DLL in Flutter The type must be a subtype

Tags: c++, flutter, dart, flutter-desktop, dart-ffi

dll` to my flutter project

In `.dll` I type function:

```
int testdll(int param) {
//...
}
```

on flutter I type this:

```
final DynamicLibrary nativePointerTestLib = DynamicLibrary.open("assets/SimpleDllFlutter.dll");

final Int Function(Int arr) testdllflutter =
nativePointerTestLib
    .lookup<NativeFunction<Int Function(Int)>>("testdll")
    .asFunction();
```

and I get error

> The type 'Int Function(Int)' must be a subtype of 'Int Function(Int)' for 'asFunction'. (Documentation)
> Int is defined in C:\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\ffi\c_type.dart (c_type.dart:77).
> Int is defined in C:\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\ffi\c_type.dart (c_type.dart:77).
> Try changing one or both of the type arguments.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try call wrond types, correct types:

```
final int Function(int arr) testdllflutter =
nativePointerTestLib
    .lookup<NativeFunction<Int32 Function(Int32)>>("testdll")
    .asFunction();
```

and it works

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up Dart integers (`int`) with C integers (`IntXX`). You are also using the old `lookup`, where the newer `lookupFunction` saves you some boilerplate.

Use this instead:

```
  final int Function(int param) testdllflutter = nativePointerTestLib
      .lookupFunction<Int32 Function(Int32), int Function(int)>('testdll');
```

`testdllflutter` is now a function taking one `int` returning `int`. The two types you need to pass to `lookupFunction` should be, first, the native-styled one, using native types that match the actual C integer sizes; then, second, the Dart-styled one, using Dart types. (The second one should match the type of the variable you are assigning it to.)